# Xcode 5.1.1 and Xcode 6.1 crash on create new Project /File/Workspace on Yosemite 10.10.2

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite

Xcode 5.1.1 and Xcode 6.1 crash on create new Project /File/Workspace on Yosemite 10.10.2
Please suggest to fix this issue

```
Bug Report
process:               Xcode [2792]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               5.1.1 (5085)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-5085000000000000~10
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [2792]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-01-11 22:07:07.203 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C94b)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        C09A26EF-E9EA-9CD0-E670-228AA19E0BA7`


Time Awake Since Boot: 13000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Application Specific Information:
Sending goNextOrFinish: to <IDEAssistantWindowController: 0x7fd6b61dcdf0> from <NSButton :0x7fd6b61c24d0>
ProductBuildVersion: 5B1008
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): *** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: sortColumn)

UserInfo: (null)
```

Hints:

```
0: Sending goNextOrFinish: to <IDEAssistantWindowController: 0x7fd6b61dcdf0> from <NSButton: 0x7fd6b61c24d0>
```

Backtrace:

```
0  0x00007fff91a14654 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
1  0x000000010e6ecb10 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
2  0x00007fff9361976e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
3  0x00007fff918fc876 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] (in CoreFoundation)
4  0x00007fff8f89478e -[FI_TNodeViewSettings setListViewSortColumn:] (in FinderKit)
5  0x00007fff8f890d0e -[FI_TNodeViewSettings refreshListViewSettings] (in FinderKit)
6  0x00007fff8f8911bb -[FI_TNodeViewSettings refreshSettings:] (in FinderKit)
7  0x00007fff8f8914c4 -[FI_TNodeViewSettings initWithNode:] (in FinderKit)
8  0x00007fff8f88fc56 +[FI_TNodeViewSettings settingsForNode:] (in FinderKit)
9  0x00007fff8f93204c -[FI_TBrowserContainerController nodeViewSettings] (in FinderKit)
10  0x00007fff8f9317ed -[FI_TBrowserContainerController initWithWindowState:targetPath:containerDelegate:] (in FinderKit)
11  0x00007fff8f8bd13e -[FIFinderViewGutsController _internalSetTargetPath:withViewStyle:] (in FinderKit)
12  0x00007fff8f8b8e8b -[FIFinderViewGutsController forceContainerToExist] (in FinderKit)
13  0x00007fff8f8b98ff -[FIFinderViewGutsController prepareToShow] (in FinderKit)
14  0x00007fff8f8c278e -[FIFinderView viewWillMoveToWindow:] (in FinderKit)
15  0x00007fff8d322b2e -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
16  0x00007fff91935385 __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
17  0x00007fff91934a89 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] (in CoreFoundation)
18  0x00007fff8da139c4 __21-[NSView _setWindow:]_block_invoke733 (in AppKit)
19  0x00007fff8d323693 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
20  0x00007fff8d3209e3 -[NSView addSubview:] (in AppKit)
21  0x00007fff8d66d82a -[NSBox setContentView:] (in AppKit)
22  0x00007fff8d8c76b5 -[NSSavePanel(NSSavePanelLayout) _layoutViewsVerticallyAndResizeWindowToLastExpandedSize:accessoryViewHeight:] (in AppKit)
23  0x00007fff8d8b27b0 -[NSSavePanel _initPanelCommon] (in AppKit)
24  0x00007fff8d8b1afa -[NSSavePanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] (in AppKit)
25  0x00007fff8d8b0fd9 +[NSSavePanel _crunchyRawUnbonedPanel] (in AppKit)
26  0x000000010f9a36ee -[IDETemplateCompletionAssistant configuredOpenPanel] (in IDEKit)
27  0x00000001163b7be3 -[Xcode3ProjectTemplateCompletionAssistant configuredSavePanel] (in Xcode3UI)
28  0x000000010f9a38db -[IDETemplateCompletionAssistant beginSheetModalForWindow:] (in IDEKit)
29  0x000000010f9a3d96 -[IDETemplateCompletionAssistant finishWithCompletionBlock:] (in IDEKit)
30  0x000000010f7f9c63 -[IDEAssistantWindowController goNextOrFinish:] (in IDEKit)
31  0x00007fff90c89cd7 _os_activity_initiate (in libsystem_trace.dylib)
32  0x00007fff8d4da541 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
33  0x000000010ec50f85 __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
34  0x000000010e6ec842 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
35  0x000000010eb1eb0e -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
36  0x00007fff8d4da340 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] (in AppKit)
37  0x00007fff8d6b014b __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
38  0x00007fff90c89cd7 _os_activity_initiate (in libsystem_trace.dylib)
39  0x00007fff8d522ec8 -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] (in AppKit)
40  0x00007fff90c89cd7 _os_activity_initiate (in libsystem_trace.dylib)
41  0x00007fff8d53d9a5 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
42  0x00007fff8d53cbd9 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
43  0x00007fff8d53c1b9 -[NSControl mouseDown:] (in AppKit)
44  0x00007fff8da3a2b1 -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:] (in AppKit)
45  0x00007fff8d4c0b4e -[NSWindow sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
46  0x00007fff8d472e51 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
47  0x000000010f699600 -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
48  0x00007fff8d2ff078 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
49  0x00007fff8d2ea464 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
50  0x00007fff8e1025c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)
51  0x0000000000000001

Performing @selector(goNextOrFinish:) from sender NSButton 0x7fd6b61c24d0

abort() called
```

Comment: I think that the question should be asked here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/